# Cropping specific part of the image

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am building a windows phone 8 camera app. After a photograph has been taken i want to give the user the option of cropping specific part of the image. Like if there are some specific objects in the image, when crop option is selected, it should highlight or outline that specific part of the image, and it should be able to crop it, rather than manually cropping it.

Any specific ways to do it?.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a `WriteableBitmap` and do a `TranslateTransform` of the original image into the `WritableBitmap`.  Something like::

```
Image workImage = new Image { Source = originalImage, Width = originalWidth, Height = originalHeight };

WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
writeableBitmap.Render(temporaryImage, new TranslateTransform { X = (originalWidth – newWidth) / -2, Y = (originalHeight – newHEight) / -2 });
writeableBitmap.Invalidate();

//... or some other stream
Stream newImageStream = new MemoryStream();
//set whatever quality settings you like if 75 is no good
writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(newImageStream, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 75);

// TODO: do something with newImageStream
```